# Remote desktop from login screen

Tags: remote-desktop, login

I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to my user account on my desktop from my dads laptop straight from the logon screen(so without logging into my dads account and then using remote desktop(he has a password which he won't tell me) we both have windows 7 professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use RDC without logging in, but if you burn a Linux LiveCD such as [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com), you can boot from it **without installing** and use tsclient which can RDC to a Windows PC:

[image]

Once arriving at a desktop from booting, navigate to **Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal**. type `tsclient` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you get an error, you need to install it, type `sudo apt-get install tsclient` and once again press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then run `tsclient` again. If you don't get an error, you'll see the window above, which you can use like regular remote desktop.